# Postman request not being updated in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I been following this yt tutorial on building a twitter backend spring boot project. When I try making an api call in postman, its showing me the 403 error. Can anyone help me?

```
Entity class:

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class ApplicationUser {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name="user_id")
 private Integer userId;
 
 @Column(name="first_name")
 private String firstName;
 
 @Column(name="last_name")
 private String lastName;
 
 @Column(unique = true)
 private String email;
 
 private String phone;
 
 @Column(name="dob")
 private Date dateOfBirth;
 
 @Column(unique = true)
 private String userName;
 
 @JsonIgnore
 //@JsonIgnore is used at field level to mark a property or list of properties to be ignored.
 private String password;
 
 @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(
         name="user_role_junction",
         joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
         inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")}
 )
 private Set<Role> authorities;

 public Integer getUserId() {
     return userId;
 }

 public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
     this.userId = userId;
 }

 public String getFirstName() {
     return firstName;
 }

 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
     this.firstName = firstName;
 }

 public String getLastName() {
     return lastName;
 }

 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
     this.lastName = lastName;
 }

 public String getEmail() {
     return email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
     this.email = email;
 }

 public String getPhone() {
     return phone;
 }

 public void setPhone(String phone) {
     this.phone = phone;
 }

 public Date getDateOfBirth() {
     return dateOfBirth;
 }

 public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
     this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
 }

 public String getUserName() {
     return userName;
 }

 public void setUserName(String userName) {
     this.userName = userName;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
     return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
     this.password = password;
 }

 public Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
     return authorities;
 }

 public void setAuthorities(Set<Role> authorities) {
     this.authorities = authorities;
 }

 public ApplicationUser(){
     this.authorities=new HashSet<>();
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "ApplicationUser{" +
             "userId=" + userId +
             ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
             ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
             ", email='" + email + '\'' +
             ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
             ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth +
             ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
             ", password='" + password + '\'' +
             ", authorities=" + authorities +
             '}';
 }
}
```

Security Config class for granting permissions (although I suspect something wrong in this)

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

private final UserRepository userRepo;
private final RoleRepository roleRepo;


@Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepo,RoleRepository roleRepo){
    this.userRepo=userRepo;
    this.roleRepo=roleRepo;
}

    public ApplicationUser registerUser(ApplicationUser user){
        Set<Role> roles=user.getAuthorities();
        roles.add(roleRepo.findByAuthority("USER").get());
        roles.add(roleRepo.findByAuthority("ADMIN").get()) ;
        user.setAuthorities(roles);
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationController(UserService userService){
        this.userService=userService;
    }
    
    //goes to http://localhost:8000/auth/register
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ApplicationUser registerUser(@RequestBody ApplicationUser user){
         userService.registerUser(user);
         return user;
    }
    

}
```

SS of postman req
[image]

Idk why the postman request is being reflected in the spring boot console but not in the database. How do I make it to save the postman request to the database?

Comment: Have you tried sending the request without the userId param?

Comment: @juanlumn Yes I tried sending it without an userId, still no difference.

Comment: @user17341714 Where is your `EnableWebSecuriy` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending "text", maybe try to change it to "JSON" here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dGvF.png)

Comment: Tried changing it to JSON but unfortunately it made no difference :(

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden indicates Authentication was successful (otherwise would return 401 unauthorized) but the authenticated user does not have access to the resource, I hope it's useful someway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).